# Execute dbo.sp_send_dbmail using vb.net

Tags: vb.net-2010

I want to execute `dbo.sp_send_dbmail` this stored procedure and I am getting following error so please anybody help me

> Could not find stored procedure 'EXEC sp_send_dbmail'

Comment: if there is additional code parts that might be useful for analyzing your problem, please also attach it in the post..

Answer (score 0):

The sp_send_dbmail stored procedure is installed in the msdb database. You must either execute sp_send_dbmail from the msdb database, or specify a three-part name for the stored procedure.